# Usage of Keytool in Windows

Tags: java, security, ssl-certificate, keytool, jks

When I type: keytool -list
in the cmd it requires a password ! It suffices to press ENTER to view a single Certificate. But when i indicate the keystore (JDKs default cacerts) it needs "changeit" and displays many more certificates !

Any explanations ?

Thanks

Comment: Please be more specific, and provide the exact commands you issue and the output.

Answer (score 0):

> When I type: keytool -list in the cmd it requires a password!

No it doesn't. It *asks* for a password.

> It suffices to press ENTER to view a single Certificate.

Which proves the point, and shows that your default keystore only contains one certificate.

> But when i indicate the keystore (JDKs default cacerts) it needs "changeit"

No it doesn't. That is the password you need to supply if you supply one, but ENTER will do, just as with your own, for listing purposes. See the tool documentation.

> and displays many more certificates!

That's because it *contains* many certificates. Unlike your default keystore. Which is `$HOME/.keystore`. Not `cacerts`.

Comment: "See the tool documentation" isn't very helpful. I've been looking for the documentation online and I can't find it, which is what led me here. Typing `keytool --help` isn't very helpful. (For example, what are my choices for the -keyalg option?) A link to some documentation would be more helpful.